# Can I read an encoded stream from a URL with WebRTC

Tags: ffmpeg, webrtc, video-streaming

I'm trying to stream the video of my C++ 3D application (similar to streaming a game).

I have encoded an H.264 video stream with the ffmpeg library (i.e. internally to my application) and can push it to a local address, e.g. `rtp://127.0.0.1:6666`, which can be played by VLC or other player (locally).

I'm not particularly wedded to h.264 at this point, or rtp. I could send as srtp if that would help.

I'd like to use WebRTC to set up a connection across different machines, but can't see in the examples how to make use of this pre-existing stream - the video and audio examples are understandably focused on getting data from devices like connected web cams, or the display.

Is what I'm thinking feasible? I.e. ideally I'd just point webRTC at my `rtp://127.0.0.1:6666` address and that would be the video stream source.
I am writing out an sdp file as well which can be read by VLC, could I use this in a similar way?

As noted in the comment below there is an example out there using go to weave some magic that enables an rtp stream to be shown in a browser via webRTC.

I am trying to find a more "standard" way to be able to set the source of a video track in webRTC to be the URL of an encoded stream. If there isn't one, that is valuable information to me too, as I can change tack and use a webrtc library to send frames directly.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC), H.264 codec is supported only in Constrained Baseline profile. There is an example for streaming a file [here](https://github.com/ashellunts/ffmpeg-to-webrtc). The example is not working... There is a connection issue (I don't think the problem is related to the input file).

Comment: Thanks, I’d seen that example but couldn’t get it to work, and couldn’t see anything else out there indicating it should, hence the qn. I was hoping there might be some clearer guidance on what the steps needed are; that example uses an sdp file which I already create from ffmpeg, I suppose I should really look at those go scripts in the example to see what they’re doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately FFMPEG doesn't support WebRTC output. It lacks support for ICE and DTLS-SRTP.

You will need to use a RTP -> WebRTC bridge. I wrote [rtp-to-webrtc](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/tree/master/examples/rtp-to-webrtc) that can do this. You can do this with lots of different WebRTC clients/servers!

If you have a particular language/paradigm that you prefer happy to provide examples for those.

Comment: Thanks, that really helps, as it's your code referred to above.  I don't want to have to use a bridge if I can help it, so I'll have a go at outputting directly into a webrtc stream.

Comment: For C/C++ you have four choices, in no particular order. https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/webrtc/index.html https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/

Comment: yeah.. i have spent today not getting as far as I'd like.. so am I correct in my interpretation that it is not exactly simple to encode my own frames (e.g. using libffmpeg) and send them (encoded) using a webrtc video stream?

Comment: and to further quiz you, something like libdatachannel, are you linking that since you'd have to use a data channel to send encoded frames? If so, what are the options for decoding browser-side?

Comment: You can easily send the encoded media, ffmpeg just doesn't support it. The linked libraries all can take the media from libffmpeg and send it. Check out https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel/tree/master/examples/streamer it takes Opus+H264 from disk and sends it the browser. The name `libdatachannel` is misleading, in your case you will not be using DataChannels at all. WebRTC sends media using RTP. Check out https://webrtcforthecurious.com it may help! It is an Open Source book I have been working on.

Comment: Your book is great!